# How to change values for a single id in a whole set of class in jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I have jquery like this:

```
$('.x').hover({
    hover_width: 300,
    hover_height: 400,
});
```

html code like this:

```
<div class='x' id='a'></div>
<div class='x'></div>
<div class='x'></div>
```

It is a very long code to actually put in, sorry to have made it shorter. I want to change the values for id 'a' & still hold the class because it uses some of the css. How to get the id inside the 'hover' in jquery & change the 'hover_width = 200' only for that id & not for the others.

I am looking for something like an if condition inside the 'hover' that gets the id name & gives value as '200' else it just says '300'. Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply use the ID selector:

```
$('#a').hover(...);
```

See http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ for a list of all selectors supported by jQuery. Since this is a superset of the CSS selectors [reading about them](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/Getting_Started/Selectors) would be a good idea, too.